# How to recruit a post doc from an area outside your labs expertise?

Tags: recruiting

I have just been given a dataset, and hopefully the money to hire a post doc to analyze it. The data set requires a post doc with experience in health informatics. No one in my deptartment, including myself, has experience with health informatics. The dataset is about 4 orders of magnitude bigger than anything anyone I know has looked at, and 2 orders of magnitude bigger than the largest published datasets in my field. How do I go about recruiting and hiring a post doc in an area outside my expertise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A time-honored method is to identify professors around the world who are experts in the desired area, contact them, and ask if they have grad students who will be finishing soon and might be interested and qualified.

Comment: Grad students or postdocs looking for a second postdoc.